# JDBC template Batch exception handling

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBC template to insert batches to MySql DB.
Since I use `&rewriteBatchedStatements=true`, If I have a primary key violation it will fail the entire batch.

The problem is I cannot know which record is the evil one who caused the batch to fail.

All I get is BatchUpdateException with an array of `-3` statuses.

I moved to use `INSERT IGNORE` but I would really like to see which records failed my batch, remove it, and persist all others.

Is this possible?  maybe with Hibernate 5?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: I wouldn't add Hibernate; it would only make your situation worse.  Better to figure out how to log messages more appropriately.

Comment: We had the same problem with db2 batches. -3 status for all items when only one item fails.